# Exsposing owa to internet but not via DMZ?

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-app, dmz

I need to give internet access to my test Exchange 2003 milieu via owa, which is on my internal network (10-network) which is a milieu whith 5 virtual machines on hyper-V!

How do I do that when using DMZ is NOT an option?

Thanks a lot in advance...

/Finn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to do port forwarding from your firewall to the specific VM running that Exchange role.